# Weyl's developement of Euler's Equations for a Spinning Top using tensor calculus

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

Equation 27 referenced in the quotation is torque equals the time
derivative of angular momentum. Equation $\eqref{29}$ is the contraction of
a position vector with the angular velocity tensor, giving the linear
velocity components of the point

$$
u_{i}=v_{ik}\xi^{k}.\tag{29}\label{29}
$$

The discussion pertains to Euclidean space with rectangular Cartesian coordinates where we may toggle indices with
impunity.

The following is from [Hermann Weyl's Space-Time-Matter](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006) beginning on page 74.  I find it difficult to follow because the notation used to distinguish between inertial and body coordinates is a bit nebulous.  The distinction between what is instantaneously invariant, and what is constant in time is tricky.  My questions are at the end.

> ### Euler's Equations for a Spinning Top

> As an exercise in tensor calculus, we shall deduce Euler's equations
> for the motion of a rigid body under no forces about a fixed point
> $O$. We write the fundamental equations (27) in the co-variant
> form
> $$
> \frac{dL_{ik}}{dt}=0
> $$
> and multiply them, for the sake of briefness, by the contra-variant
> components $w^{ik}$ of an arbitrary skew-symmetrical tensor which
> is constant (independent of the time), and apply contraction with
> respect to $i$ and $k$. If we put $H_{ik}$ equal to the sum
> $$
> \sum_{m}mu_{i}\xi_{k}
> $$
> which is to be taken over all the points of mass, we get
> $$
> \tfrac{1}{2}L_{ik}w^{ik}=H_{ik}w^{ik}=H,
> $$
> an invariant, and we can compress our equation into
> $$
> \frac{dH}{dt}=0.\tag{32}\label{32}
> $$
> If we introduce the expressions \eqref{29} for $u_{i}$, and the
> tensor of inertia $T$, then
> $$
> H_{ik}=v_{ir}T_{k}^{r}.\tag{33}\label{33}
> $$

> We have hitherto assumed that a co-ordinate system which is fixed
> in *space* has been used. The components $T$ of inertia then
> change with the distribution of matter in the course of time. If,
> however, in place of this we use a co-ordinate system which is fixed
> in the *body*, and consider the symbols so far used as referring
> to the components of the corresponding tensors with respect to this
> co-ordinate system, whereas we distinguish the components of the same
> tensors with respect to the co-ordinate system fixed in space by a
> horizontal bar, the equation \eqref{32} remains valid on account
> of the invariance of $H$. The $T_{i}^{k}$'s are now constants; on
> the other hand, however, the $w^{ik}$'s vary with the time. Our equation
> gives us
> $$
> \frac{dH_{ik}}{dt}w^{ik}+H_{ik}\frac{dw^{ik}}{dt}=0.\tag{34}\label{34}
> $$

> To determine $\dfrac{dw^{ik}}{dt}$, we choose two arbitrary vectors
> fixed in the body, of which the co-variant components in the co-ordinate
> system attached to the body are $\xi_{i}$ and $\eta_{i}$ respectively.
> These quantities are thus constants, but their components $\bar{\xi}_{i}$,
> $\bar{\eta}_{i}$ in the space co-ordinate system are functions of
> the time. Now,
> $$
> w^{ik}\xi_{i}\eta_{k}=\bar{w}^{ik}\bar{\xi}_{i}\bar{\eta}_{k},
> $$
> and hence, differentiating with respect to the time
> $$
> \frac{dw^{ik}}{dt}\xi_{i}\eta_{k}=\bar{w}^{ik}\left(\frac{d\bar{\xi}_{i}}{dt}\bar{\eta}_{k}+\bar{\xi}_{i}\frac{d\bar{\eta}_{k}}{dt}\right).\tag{35}\label{35}
> $$
> By formula \eqref{29}
> $$
> \frac{d\bar{\xi}_{i}}{dt}=\bar{v}_{ir}\bar{\xi}^{r}=\bar{v}_{i}^{r}\bar{\xi}_{r}.
> $$
> We thus get for the right-hand side of \eqref{35}
> $$
> \bar{w}^{ik}\left(\bar{v}_{i}^{r}\bar{\xi}_{r}\bar{\eta}_{k}+\bar{v}_{k}^{r}\bar{\xi}_{i}\bar{\eta}_{r}\right),
> $$
> and as this is an invariant, **we may remove the bars**, obtaining
> $$
> \xi_{i}\eta_{k}\frac{dw^{ik}}{dt}=w^{ik}\left(\xi_{r}\eta_{k}v_{i}^{r}+\xi_{i}\eta_{r}v_{k}^{r}\right).
> $$
> This holds identically in $\xi$ and $\eta$; thus if the $H^{ik}$
> are arbitrary numbers,
> $$
> H_{ik}\frac{dw^{ik}}{dt}=w^{ik}\left(v_{i}^{r}H_{rk}+v_{k}^{r}H_{ir}\right).
> $$
> If we take the $H_{ik}$'s to be the quantities which we denoted above
> by this symbol, the second term of \eqref{34} is determined, and
> our equation becomes
> $$
> \left\{ \frac{dH_{ik}}{dt}+\left(v_{i}^{r}H_{rk}+v_{k}^{r}H_{ir}\right)\right\} w^{ik}=0,
> $$
> which is an identity in the skew-symmetrical tensor $w^{ik}$; hence
> $$
> \frac{d\left(H_{ik}-H_{ki}\right)}{dt}+\left[v_{i}^{r}H_{rk}+v_{k}^{r}H_{ir}-v_{k}^{r}H_{ri}-v_{i}^{r}H_{kr}\right]=0.
> $$
> We shall now substitute the expression \eqref{33} for $H_{ik}$.
> Since, on account of the symmetry of $T_{ik}$,
> $$
> v_{k}^{r}H_{ir}\left(=v_{k}^{r}v_{i}^{s}T_{rs}\right)
> $$
> is also symmetrical in $i$ and $k$, the two last terms of the sum
> in the square brackets destroy one another. If we now put the symmetrical
> tensor
> $$
> v_{i}^{r}v_{kr}=g_{rs}v_{i}^{r}v_{k}^{s}=\left(v,v\right){}_{ik}
> $$
> we finally get our equations into the form
> $$
> \frac{d}{dt}\left(v_{ir}T_{k}^{r}-v_{kr}T_{i}^{r}\right)=\left(v,v\right){}_{ir}T_{k}^{r}-\left(v,v\right){}_{kr}T_{i}^{r}.
> $$

> It is well known that we may introduce a Cartesian co-ordinate system
> composed of the three principal axes of inertia, so that in these
> $$
> g_{ik}=\begin{cases}
> 1 & (i=k),\\
> 0 & (i\neq k),
> \end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad T_{ik}=0\quad\text{(for } i\neq k\text{).}
> $$
> If we then write $T_{1}$ in place of $T_{1}^{1}$, and do the same
> for the remaining indices, our equations in this co-ordinate system
> assume the simple form
> $$
> \left(T_{i}+T_{k}\right)\frac{dv_{ik}}{dt}=\left(T_{k}-T_{i}\right)\left(v,v\right){}_{ik}.
> $$
> These are the differential equations for the components $v_{ik}$
> of the unknown angular velocity---equations which, as is known, may
> be solved in elliptic functions of $t$. The principal moments of
> inertia $T_{i}$ which occur here are connected with those, $T_{i}^{*}$,
> given in accordance with the usual definitions by the equations
> $$
> T_{1}^{*}=T_{2}+T_{3},\qquad T_{2}^{*}=T_{3}+T_{1},\qquad T_{3}^{*}=T_{1}+T_{2}.
> $$

> The above treatment of the problem of rotation may, in contra-distinction
> to the usual method, be transposed, word for word, from three-dimensional
> space to multi-dimensional spaces. This is, indeed, irrelevant in
> practice. On the other hand, the fact that we have freed ourselves
> from the limitation to a definite dimensional number and that we have
> formulated physical laws in such a way that the dimensional number
> appears *accidental* in them, gives us an assurance that we
> have succeeded fully in grasping them mathematically.

### Questions

The first term on the left-hand side of \eqref{34} appears to mean

$$
\frac{dH_{ik}}{dt}w^{ik}=\frac{dv_{i}^{j}}{dt}\sum_{m}m\xi_{j}\xi_{k}w^{ik},
$$

because the position vectors are constant over time relative the coordinate
system fixed in the body. Thus the components of the angular velocity
tensor relative to the body's coordinate system are (in general) time-variable.
Is this correct?

The statement (following \eqref{35}) that

$$
\bar{w}^{ik}\left(\bar{v}_{i}^{r}\bar{\xi}_{r}\bar{\eta}_{k}+\bar{v}_{k}^{r}\bar{\xi}_{i}\bar{\eta}_{r}\right)
$$

is invariant appears to mean that the value is the same in both the
inertial and body coordinates at a given instant in time, but not
necessarily constant over time. Again, is this correct?

Finally, is it correct that all expressions following **"we may remove
the bars"** are in terms of body coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation
$$
\frac{dH_{ik}}{dt}w^{ik}=\frac{dv^i_j}{dt}\sum_m m\,\xi_j\,\xi_k\,w^{ik}
$$
looks correct. Yes, the position vector $\xi$ in the body is constant in time. Apart from $w^{ik}$, the only time dependent quantity in this equation is the angular velocity $v\,.$

The invariance of the quantity (in space coordinates)
$$
\bar{w}^{ik}(\bar{v}^r_i\,\bar{\xi}_r\,\bar{\eta}_k+\bar{v}^r_k\,\bar{\xi}_i\,\bar{\eta}_r)\quad\quad\quad(A)
$$
means, not time independence, but that it is equal to the same expression in body coordinates
$$
w^{ik}(v^r_i\,\xi_r\,\eta_k+v^r_k\,\xi_i\,\eta_r)\,.
$$
The map that takes any vector from body to space coordinates preserves the cross product and the scalar product. The expression $v^r_i\,\xi_r$ is the cross product of angular velocity and position. Hence, it does not change when bars are put on.
Likewise, the cross product $v^r_k\,\eta_r$ does not change. I read Weyl's relationship
$$
w^{ik}\,\xi_i\,\eta_k=\bar{w}^{ik}\,\bar{\xi}_i\,\bar{\eta}_k
$$
as the definition of $w^{ik}$ given $\bar{w}^{ik}\,.$ Eq. (A) is the sum of two such expressions. Therefore, one can lift the bars in (A).

I think it is a good exercise to compare Weyl's approach and notation to Arnold's in  Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics where the distinction between space and body coordinates is made very clear.

Comment: I read Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations a thousand years ago.  His Classical Mechanics is high on my list of good intentions.  I read $w^{ik}\,\xi_i\,\eta_k=\bar{w}^{ik}\,\bar{\xi}_i\,\bar{\eta}_k$ to be a consequence of promulgating the invariance of $H$.  So we agree that it requires a definition at some point.  I once asked John Archibald Wheeler if he was familiar with Weyl's book.  His response was "I read that book about once a decade, and learn something new every time."

Comment: Weyl's text is intriguing and I am keen to work throught it completely. Are we sure that $\dot H=0$ holds in the body coordinates? The Euler equation in Arnold's book says $\dot{\mathbf{M}}=[\mathbf{M},\Omega]$ and this is clearly not zero in general. In contrast to $\dot{\mathbf{m}}$ (angular momentum conservation in space).

Comment: I highly recommend having access to the German language original.  There are numerous confusing typos throughout the translation.

Comment: In fact, $H$ is the same in both coordinates. This is actually the ingenious heart of Weyl's approach and simply follows from the definition of $\bar{w}^{ik}\,.$